# Create a JSON string from column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I mutate a Pandas DataFrame with a series of dictionaries.

Given the following DataFrame:

```
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

# add dict series
df = df.assign(my_dict="{}")
df.my_dict = df.my_dict.apply(json.loads)
```

| Name | Age | my_dict |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tom | 10 | {} |
| nick | 15 | {} |
| juli | 14 | {} |

How would I operate on column `my_dict` and mutate it as follows:

Age > 10

| Name | Age | my_dict |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tom | 10 | {"age>10": false} |
| nick | 15 | {"age>10": true} |
| juli | 14 | {"age>10": true} |

And then mutate again:

Name = "tom":

| Name | Age | my_dict |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tom | 10 | {"age>10": false, "name=tom": true} |
| nick | 15 | {"age>10": true, "name=tom", false} |
| juli | 14 | {"age>10": true, "name=tom", false} |

I'm interested in the process of mutating the dictionary, the rules are arbitrary examples.

Comment: There are many issue with your example, including: 1- `"{}"` is a string, not a dictionary, 2- you do not explain where the new data should come from. Ideally you should create this column only once as the operation of mutating it will be expensive

Comment: If you read the question, in the example I apply `json.loads` to transform the string.

The new data comes from the conditions which are clearly described in the question.

Comment: Missing assignment: `df = df.assign(my_dict="{}")`

Comment: pandas isn't of great help here at all FYI compared to list of dicts

Comment: @Either what would you recommend? Open to better suggestions!

Comment: list of dicts as said above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['my_dict'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['my_dict'] | {'Age': x['Age'] > 10}, axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
   Name  Age         my_dict
0   tom   10  {'Age': False}
1  nick   15   {'Age': True}
2  juli   14   {'Age': True}
```

Add a new condition:

```
df['my_dict'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['my_dict'] | {'Name': x['Name'] == 'tom'}, axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
   Name  Age                       my_dict
0   tom   10  {'Age': False, 'Name': True}
1  nick   15  {'Age': True, 'Name': False}
2  juli   14  {'Age': True, 'Name': False}
```

Obviously if you want to convert to json, use:

```
>>> df['my_dict'].apply(json.dumps)
0    {"Age": false, "Name": true}
1    {"Age": true, "Name": false}
2    {"Age": true, "Name": false}
Name: my_dict, dtype: object
```

Comment: @shbfy This is however not "dynamic" like you originally requested, there is no mutation of an object, just a simple one-time creation

Answer (score 1):

`apply` is generally supposed to be slow. Here are two alternatives, both using list comprehensions, which according to this [highly voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/8790507), is slightly faster than apply.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

# Define your weird func: takes a row of df and returns your dict
def weird_func2(row):
    return {"name=tom":row["Name"]=="tom", "age>10":row["Age"]>10}

# add dict series
df["mydict"] = [weird_func2(i[1]) for i in df.iterrows()]
df
```

Or you can try:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

# Define your weird func: takes a row of df and returns your dict
def weird_func(name, age):
    return {"name=tom":name=="tom", "age>10":age>10}

# add dict series
df["mydict"] = [weird_func(name, age) for name, age in zip(df["Name"], df["Age"])]
df
```